# How to replace a huge lambda expression with a private method adding a parameter?

Tags: c#

Assuming that we have the following code (which a rather extensive specification of the access conditions) I wanted to refactor it. There's a bunch of such policies very similar to each other, with only a tiny variation in a special claim.

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
  options.AddPolicy("ExtensivePolicy_A",
    config => config.RequireClaim("special_claim", "dedicated_value_to_A")
     .RequireClaim("claim1", "value1") ...
  );
  ... 
  options.AddPolicy("ExtensivePolicy_Z",
    config => config.RequireClaim("special_claim", "dedicated_value_to_Z")
     .RequireClaim("claim1", "value1") ...
  );
}
```

The attempt based on [e.g. this](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/csharp/csharp-action-delegate), gave me this.

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
  options.AddPolicy("ExtensivePolicy_A", ConfigPolicyA);
  ...
  options.AddPolicy("ExtensivePolicy_Z", ConfigPolicyZ);
}

private static void ConfigPolicyA(AuthorizationPolicyBuilder builder) { ... }
...
private static void ConfigPolicyZ(AuthorizationPolicyBuilder builder) { ... }
```

It's much cleaner but still screams parameterization, as the only difference in the config delegates (actions, funcs whatever they call it), is a tiny detail. Optimally, I'd like my privates to look something along the lines of the following.

```
private static void ConfigPolicy(AuthorizationPolicyBuilder builder, string special) { ... }
```

And the call to it would pass a parameter.

```
options.AddPolicy("MarketingPolicy", ConfigPolicy("a"));
```

However, I can't get it to work. The compiler complains about the action type being wrong. The original intellisense tells me that I'm supposed to pass something of type `Action<AuthorizationPolicyBuilder>`, which is kind of against my method's signature (being `void`). However, it seems to compile whereas the version that returns said type gets the compiler whining about error converting method group to `AuthorizationPolicy` (which is misleading because that type is a signature of another overloaded method).

My best attempt based on [this blog (actions with lambda expression)](http://dotnetpattern.com/csharp-action-delegate) went as far as this.

```
private static Action<AuthorizationPolicyBuilder, string> test1
  = builder => { ... };
```

However, trying to introduce the extra string parameter fails miserably.

```
private static Action<AuthorizationPolicyBuilder, string> test2 
  = (builder, special) => { ... };
```

What should I google for to get relevant examples, which I'm sure there are a gazillion of out there? I've found examples on generics and methods as paameters but nothing that tipped me over to aha-side.

Comment: `options.AddPolicy("MarketingPolicy", config => ConfigPolicy(config, "a"));`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# define function with partial application as delegate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40146859/c-sharp-define-function-with-partial-application-as-delegate)

Comment: @GSerg That might be one way to go. However, I'd like to replace the **entire** content of the second parameter (i.e. `config=>blaha-blaha`) and assign it **some**thing that I declare below. **And** I want that something to be parameterized, so that I can pass a string to blaha-blaha but receive the final thingy.

Comment: @GSerg My last comment was to your first suggestion (not bad, to be honest). As for the second one, it resembles quite a lot the sample I show using definition of `Action`. That fails in my case due to the extra string passed in (see the edit I just made). A single parameter to the action works as expected, though.

Comment: @GSerg Are you claiming that I can't exchange `(config)=>blah for (config, "fix_value_here")=>blah` in C#? I'm comparing to (the principle of) calling a method `Hazaa(5)` while the signature is `void Hazaa(int,string param="")`. I was wishing to replace the passed in builder to config and restructure it to be `config,"my_fix_value"` and **then** pass it on to my

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```cs
private static Action<AuthorizationPolicyBuilder> ConfigBuilderFactory(string param)
{
  return builder => builder
    .RequireClaim("special_claim", param)
    .RequireClaim("claim1", "value1")
    ...;
}
```

```cs
options.AddPolicy("ExtensivePolicy_A", ConfigBuilderFactory("a"));
options.AddPolicy("ExtensivePolicy_Z", ConfigBuilderFactory("z"));
```

Comment: Yes, this is perfect. I'll take the liberty to change the name of the policy to more generic form that follows the formulation in the original question. I suspect that you picked it up from my comments where I posted the actual production code by quickstake.